# Not all code paths return a value, I don't know what to do

Tags: c#

```cs
    private static string GetMinX(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        double x1 = 0;
        double x2 = 0;
        double x3 = 0;
        if (b * b - 4 * a * c > 0)
        {
            x1 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a;
            x2 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a;
            if (x2 > x1)
                return x1.ToString();
            else
                return x2.ToString(); 
        }
        if (b * b - (4 * a * c) == 0)
        {
            x3 = -b / 2 * a;
            return x3.ToString();
        }
        if (b * b - 4 * a * c < 0)  
            return "IMP";
    }
```

So every condition returns value (d > 0, == 0, < 0). Why does it write not all code paths return a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to use `if/else if/else` statement, it should be more efficient. Also you can use `Math.Min` and discard `x3`.

```
private static string GetMinX(int a, int b, int c)
{
    double x1, x2, m;
    m = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if (m > 0)
    {
        x1 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a;
        x2 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a;
        return Math.Min(x1, x2).ToString();
    }
    else if (m == 0)
    {
        x1 = -b / 2 * a;
        return x3.ToString();
    }
    else
        return "IMP";
}
```

You can also use only one condition by combining the first two cases:

```
private static string GetMinX(int a, int b, int c)
{
    double x1, x2, m;
    m = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if (m >= 0)
    {
        x1 = (-b - Math.Sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a;
        x2 = (-b + Math.Sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a;
        return Math.Min(x1, x2).ToString();
    }
    else
        return "IMP";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because the last condition `if (b * b - 4 * a * c < 0)` has no else case and there is no return statement following it.

This condition might always true because of your logic, but C# doesn't know that. C# just assumes that any condition can be true or false (except when the condition is a constant expression).

You have two cases:

1. Either this condition is supposed to be always true: then just drop the condition and always return "IMP". This is the case here.
2. This condition might be false sometimes: then add another `return` statement at the end.

```
private static string GetMinX(int a, int b, int c)
{
    int discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if (discriminant > 0) {
        double root = Math.Sqrt(discriminant);
        double x1 = (-b - root) / (2 * a); // Put brackets around the divisor!
        double x2 = (-b + root) / (2 * a); // Put brackets around the divisor!
        if (x1 < x2)
            return x1.ToString();
        else
            return x2.ToString();
    }
    if (discriminant == 0) {
        double x = -b / (2 * a); // Put brackets around the divisor!
        return x.ToString();
    }
    return "IMP";
}
```

It is also good to do the same calculation only once and to store the result in a variable.

There is a subtle error in `... / 2 * a`. It should be `... / (2 * a)`, otherwise you divide by 2 and then multiply by a. But you want to divide by `2 * a`.

There is no point in assigning `0` to `x1`, `x2` and `x3`. These values will never be used. Better declare the variables where they are used (in the local code block) and initialize them directly with the right value. Their scope will be limited to this code block. This means that for instance `x1` does not exist after the first if-statement and will therefore never have an undetermined value.

"if x1 is less than x2" sounds more natural than "if x2 is greater than x1", since you want to know which one the smallest is. But both variants will work.